# Concentration Inequality for the Negative Binomial Distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, concentration-of-measure

I was wondering if there is any well-known concentration inequality for the Negative Binomial distribution with parameters $r$ and $p$. This random variable is defined as the number of independent Bernoulli trials needed to reach $r$ successes, where each trial has probability $p$ of success. The mean of such a random variable is $r/p$, so I am looking for a concentration result for this random variable about $r/p$. Thanks!

Comment: When you say "concentration result" do you mean something like variance?